# Get all objects of a given structure, and their global names

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following objects:

```
gray       =    (132, 132, 132)
green      =    (0, 104, 0)
red        =    (168, 0, 68)
```

How can I obtain all such `globals()` of this form (RGB) and the name of the corresponding objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following shortcut?

```
ls = [(key, value) for key, value in globals().items() if isinstance(value, tuple) and len(value) == 3]
```

which creates a list of tuples containing your colors.

**Edit**:

The previous solution would match also tuples of the form

```
("hello", "blah", 7)
```

That is, tuples whose elements could also not be `int`s.

To prevent this, use the following solution which only accepts tuples whose elements are all `int`s.

```
ls = [(key, value) for key, value in globals().items() if isinstance(value, tuple) and len(value) == 3 and all(isinstance(e, int) for e in value) ]
```

This is similar to what falsetru is doing but just in a compacted way.

Comment: Thank you!...it was very hard to choose between the two answers...Both are great.
Yours happens to be closer to what I am looking for as I am trying to create a dictionary. Many thanks to @falsetru as well.

Comment: @lnNoam See my edit with a new maybe better solution.

Comment: It is implemented in such a way that such an occurrence is impossible...but no harm in being careful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance), you can check the type of the objects. And using [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars), you will get mapping of variable names to values.

```
gray = (132, 132, 132)
green = (0, 104, 0)
red = (168, 0, 68)
somethingelse = 0

for key, value in vars().items():
    is_rgb = (
        isinstance(value, tuple) and
        len(value) == 3 and
        all(isinstance(x, int) for x in value)
    )
    if is_rgb:
        print(key)
```

---

Another way: [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

```
gray = (132, 132, 132)
green = (0, 104, 0)
red = (168, 0, 68)
somethingelse = 0

for key, value in vars().items():
    try:
        _, _, _ = value
        if isinstance(value, tuple):
            print(key)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass
```